# LM317 adjustable current regulator for LED

Tags: circuit-design, led-driver, current-limiting, constant-current, lm317

I am driving a 10 W LED from a LM317 regulator. With a variable resistor in between the OUT and ADJ pins of the LM317, I can easily get an adjustable current source (20-350 mA). However, I need to control the brightness through the microcontroller. Can someone please help me identify the changes that need to be made in the circuit attached so I can get adjustable current controlled through PWM of the microcontroller?

[image: Here is used circuit]

Comment: do you want a steady adjustable current, or would adjusting brightness with PWM (which is the way most people do it) be OK?

Comment: @Neil_UK Yes, I would be adjusting brightness with PWM

Comment: Is the actual input voltage 5V as shown?

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to PWM that with a microcontroller is to use the 317 itself to do the heavy lifting.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fP5i1B.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

When the MCU output is high, D1 is reverse biassed, and the 317 regulation works normally.

When the MCU output is low, D1 pulls the adjust pin low, limiting the output voltage from the 317.

R2 is added so that D1 doesn't have to pull down the full output current. The most it will source is 1.2/R2, so a 240Ω value would require the MCU output to sink 5 mA. Any value in that ballpark will do. It has to be low enough to supply the Iadj current to the 317. Although the accuracy of any small voltage drop across it is irrelevant in the face of the adjustable R1, any drop there eats into the voltage headroom of the circuit.

It doesn't appear to me that the OP's circuit will work as expected with white LEDs, only with red or IR. If it does work at all when on, I expect the 317 is saturated, and control is by R1 from the PSU voltage. It will still work for PWM'ing though.

If you switch the MCU pin between analogue input (high impedance, tolerates intermediate voltage) and output low, you don't even need D1. Without the voltage drop of D1, the output voltage should be low enough to turn off red LEDs.